# Why should user have to set parallelism explicitly

Tags: apache-flink

I kicked off a flink application with `n` TaskManagers and `s` slots for each TaskManager, so that, My application will have n*s slots.

That means, flink could be able to run `n*s` subtasks at most at the same time. But why flink doesn't try to use most resources to run as many subtasks as possible, and bother end users to set the parallelism explicitly?

For the flink beginners that don't know the parallelism setting(default is 1), it will always run only one subtask even given more resources!

I would like to know the design considerations here, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Flink cluster can also be used by multiple users or a single user can run multiple jobs on a cluster. Such clusters are not sized to run a single job but to run multiple jobs. In such environments its not desirable if jobs grab all available resources by default.

Comment: Thanks @fabian-hueske, that makes sense.One further question per your answer, If I want to submit application with `flink run -m yarn-cluster`, would it be desirable to set the parallelism the same as numTaskManager * numSlotPerTaskManager?

Comment: If you submit a job with the `flink run -m yarn-cluster` command, you start a Flink cluster in "job mode", which executes a single job (see [docs here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/yarn_setup.html#run-a-single-flink-job-on-yarn)). This should behave similar to what you want. The number of started TMs is computed based on the parallelism of the job divided by slots-per-TM as in Flink's configuration.

Comment: Thanks @fabian-hueske, it makes sense and clear to me now, thanks